# Case test if substring exist and replace with blank

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I need to cleanup a set of companies name by replacing : INC, LTD, LTD. , INC. , others, with a empty space when they are individual words ( with one blank space before the word i.e. Incoming INC) and not letters part of company name i.e. INComing Money.

The logic I tried :

```
case
when FINDSTRING([Trade Name]," INC",1) > 0 then REPLACE([Trade Name]," INC","")
when FINDSTRING([Trade Name]," LTD",1) > 0 then REPLACE([Trade Name]," LTD","")
ELSE [Trade Name]
```

I tried SSIS expresion in a derived column :

```
FINDSTRING( [Trade Name] ," INC",1) ? REPLACE([Trade Name]," INC","") : 
FINDSTRING([Trade Name]," LTD",1) ? REPLACE([Trade Name]," LTD",""):
```

The error received:

> Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [1]]: Attempt to find the
>   input column named "A" failed with error code 0xC0010009. The input
>   column specified was not found in the input column collection.

Comment: Somehow is working in this form:                                                 FINDSTRING([Trade Name]," INC",1) != 0 ?  REPLACE([Trade Name]," INC","") : FINDSTRING([Trade Name]," LTD",1) != 0 ? REPLACE([Trade Name]," LTD","") : FINDSTRING([Trade Name],"&",1) !=  0 ? REPLACE([Trade Name],"&"," ") : FINDSTRING([Trade Name],". ",1) != 0 ? REPLACE([Trade Name],". "," ") : FINDSTRING([Trade Name],",",1) != 0 ? REPLACE([Trade Name],","," ") : FINDSTRING([Trade Name],". ",1) != 0 ? REPLACE([Trade Name],". ","") : [Trade_Name].                      One issue is not working for dot ' . '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar case it is easier to use a Script Component to clean this column, you can simply split the column based on spaces then re concatenate the parts that are not equal to `INC`, you can use the following method to do that, or you can simple use `RegEx.Replace()` method to replace values based on regular expressions:

```cs
string value = "";
string[] parts = Row.TradeName.Split(' ');

foreach(string str in parts){

    if(str != "INC"){

    value += " " + str;

    }

}

Row.outTradeName = value.TrimStart();
```

Comment: thank @hadi. I accept as an answer as point me in right direction:                 
SELECT [Legal Name] ,newLegalName = (REPLACE ([Legal Name]+ '' , 'INC', '   ')) from [table]  WHERE 'INC'  IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT([Legal  Name], ' '))    order by [legal name]